# How to authorize certain domain user in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I marked my controller as below:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Marketing")]
[Authorize(Users = "DOMAIN\\MyUsername")]
public class ContactsController : Controller
```

I am not in "Marketing" role, but I added my own username to Users.

When I navigate to Contacts/Index, or any other action, I am first prompted to give credentials, and then I see error 401 - Unauthorized. 

In Detailed Error Information under Logon User is DOMAIN\MyUsername.

**Why my user is not authorized?**

My browser is Chrome and I'm using IIS Express as development server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case two attributes are used you are saying that your user has to be a DOMAIN\MyUserName AND he has also a Marketing role. You have to use only one attribute.

```
[Authorize(Users = "DOMAIN\\MyUsername", Roles = "Marketing")]
public class ContactsController : Controller
```